# Should questions when migrated be shown in the "New Questions" list?

Tags: discussion, migration

Since they are in fact new to that particular site. They do appear in the frontpage view but I'm wondering if they benefit from appearing in the "New Questions" list.

It has it's pitfalls. Like what if a 2 year old question is migrated. (and more) 
And it has it's advantages. Like people who only monitor the "New Questions" list and the frontpage list can often be to chaotic.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, I think the timestamp should be reset. I mean, *it's a new question*... it just happens to have a closed, locked, doppelganger on another site. Give it a fresh start.

Answer (score 3):

I have wanted either that or a new listing of "recently migrated" (something the mods would be very thankful for because of the inevitability of cleanup requirements).

Keeping it in the middle of the list has a tendency for it to get lost in the shuffle and it may not get the attention it needs.

Comment: +1 for a tool to show recently migrated (at least for mods)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a great idea. Even if the question is very old, the fact that it was on the wrong site means that it was not viewed by the correct audience. If a question is moved to Server Fault it is still a new question there and deserves a fair shot at getting answered.